# How to make full page transition effect like this using react.js?

Tags: reactjs

now I am trying to make landing page like this : https://www.kakaocorp.com/page/service/service/KakaoTalk

if you scroll down the page mentioned above, you can see text and smartphone image. if you continue scroll down, text and image change without scrolling effect.

how can I implement this effect ? any hints, keywords or references are welcome.

I used fullpage.js for full-page scrolling, but I don't know fullpage.js can implement this.

I don't care what else I can do.

thank you.